# How can a program sign for an ATA?

Tags: spl-token, program

I want a program to store some USDC token. I created the account this way:

```
const programAssociatedTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(provider.connection, creator, mint, program.programId);
```

The ATA is associated to the program from my understanding. I would like to sign on chain to be able to move some USDC from the ATA to anywhere else, I am not sure how to do it.

The contents of the accounts is set to ... for simplification. I don't know what to put on signers_seed (the last arg of invoke_signed).

```
        let transfer_to_buyer = transfer(..., &[],10)?;

        invoke_signed(
            &transfer_to_buyer,
            &[...],
            &[&[]],
        )?;
```

Basically I would like a program to hold some USDC token and only the program can move these USDC where he wants, is there an example on how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea invoking the signer, however on Solana, programs can’t sign for themselves.

What they can do however is sign transactions for addresses derived from them (PDAs). Take a look [here](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts) if you don’t know how PDAs work yet.

What your task is going to boil down to:

• create a PDA

• create the ATA for that PDA

• use the seeds you used to create the PDA to sign/pass into the instruction within your program function. (these are the signer seeds you’re currently missing)

(Excuse my lack of code, currently writing this from my phone)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know why I don't succeed to sign:

How the PDA is created:
```
    const [store] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      // We use the 2 argument because a u16 is 2x a u8.
      [creator.publicKey.toBuffer(), new anchor.BN(country).toBuffer("le", 2)],
      program.programId,
    );
```

I am not sure how to sign on chain:

Comment: When creating and initializing your PDA, make sure to store the bump for it. The Bump needs to be included in the signer seeds when creating the cpi call :)